# regex issues file extension Python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, file

import re, urllib

```
def get_files(page):
    a = urllib.urlopen(page)
    b = a.read()
    c = re.findall("([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.{1}(jpg|bmp|docx|gif))",b)
    return c 
def main():
    print get_files("http://www.soc.napier.ac.uk/~40001507/CSN08115/cw_webpage/index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

After I ran this code, I had an issue with its regex, hence the answer will be like this:

```
[('clown.gif', 'gif'), ('sleeper.jpg', 'jpg'), ('StarWarsReview.docx', 'docx'), ('wargames.jpg', 'jpg'), ('nothingtoseehere.docx', 'docx'), ('starwars.jpg', 'jpg'), ('logo.jpg', 'jpg'), ('certified.jpg', 'jpg'), ('clown.gif', 'gif'), ('essays.gif', 'gif'), ('big.jpg', 'jpg'), ('Doc100.docx', 'docx'), ('FavRomComs.docx', 'docx'), ('python.bmp', 'bmp'), ('dingbat.jpg', 'jpg')]
```

I don't want the result to be like this `('clown.gif', 'gif')` all I want it to be like is `['clown.gif','sleeper.jpg']` and so on

Is there anyway to do it?? and get red of the tuple??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to turn your group into [a non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon).

```
def get_files(page):
    a = urllib.urlopen(page)
    b = a.read()
    c = re.findall("([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.{1}(?:jpg|bmp|docx|gif))", b)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing double capturing of the extension, try with regex below, `?:` means non-capturing group

```
re.findall("([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.{1}(?:jpg|bmp|docx|gif))", b)
```

i simplify your regex to below, the `{1}` seems redundant, and using `\w` and `\d` for word and number group

```
re.findall("([\w\d]+\.(?:jpg|bmp|docx|gif))", b)
```

Comment: I see you reduce the redundant, and it would work without them. thank you